# what am doing in my program for the given question?

Tags: java

Question Given 2 int values, return true if one is negative and one is positive. Except if the parameter "negative" is true, then return true only if both are negative.

```
public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative) {
      
    if (negative == true) {
        if (a<0 && b<0) {
            return true;
        }
        else if ( (a<0 && b>0) || (a>0 &&b<0) ) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If negative is false, the methods has to return if one value is postive while the other is negative. Now, look at your code and tell us, what it does if negative is false.

Comment: Your `else if` is on the wrong `if`.

Comment: You are: 1. formatting your code poorly 2. Not testing your code -> you are not noticing obvious bugs in the logic.

Comment: Your IDE or editor probably has a builtin code formatter. Highly recommended to use after each edit (you can typically set it to auto format on save). Formatting helps a lot to see which else belongs to which if. Would not put `{` on the next line after the `if` or `else` because code takes so much space then but that's preference.

Comment: `return ((a < 0 ? 1 : 0) + (b < 0 ? 1 : 0)) == (negative ? 2 : 1);` counting negatives makes this a lot simpler.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean numberSignTest(int a, int b, boolean bothAreNegative) {
  if(bothAreNegative) {
    if( a < 0 && b < 0 ){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  } else if( a < 0 || b < 0) {
    return (a*b < 0);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

jshell> numberSignTest(-3, 2, true)
$30 ==> false

jshell> numberSignTest(3, 2, true)
$31 ==> false

jshell> numberSignTest(3, -2, true)
$32 ==> false

jshell> numberSignTest(-3, -2, true)
$33 ==> true

jshell> numberSignTest(-3, -2, false)
$34 ==> false

jshell> numberSignTest(3, 2, false)
$35 ==> false

jshell> numberSignTest(-3, 2, false)
$36 ==> true

jshell> numberSignTest(3, -2, false)
$37 ==> true
```